# How to compare records in the same table using SQL to find difference?

Tags: sql

I want to compare two dispense transactions and find out if same drug was dispensed twice within 5 day window. How can I write SQL to compare these transactions and report?

| patient_id | doctor_id | rx_number | pharmacy_id | drug_id | ship_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1234 | 1234 | rx_1234 | ph_1234 | 1234 | 2022-06-28 |
| 1234 | 1234 | rx_1234 | ph_1234 | 1234 | 2022-07-01 |

Comment: Most sql engines support the window function `LAG` which finds the previous records partitioned by some column.  For example `LAG(ship_date) OVER (PARTITION BY drug_id ORDER BY ship_date)` finds the timing of the previous shipment of the same drug.  This will allows you to filter the drugs shipment within 5 day interval.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms

Answer (score 0):

EXISTS clause can be used for this purpose:
This one returns the row from the table if there is another row for the same drug within 5 days of ship_date:

```
select *
from MyTbl T1
where exists 
     (select * 
      from MyTbl T2
      where T2.drug_id=T1.drug_id
        and abs(datediff(day,T1.ship_date, T2.ship_date))<=5
     )
```

The syntax for the 'number of days between two dates' is for SQL Server and it can change from one RDBMS product to other. You didn't specify what you use.
This query returns both rows (the earlier and the later shipment); you didn't specify the desired output.
I assumed ship_date=dispensed date.

Comment: Use a actual date comparison (Date - 5 Days). Absolute value looks in both directions anyway and isn't what you need.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, but `dispensed twice within 5 day window` could mean either way; I would leave it to OP but he is no longer interested, by the look of it!

Comment: Well that is definitely going to be a slower query.

Comment: yes, only if there is an index on ship_date and if the server would choose to use it.